# undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined

I'm using paperclip and cocoon to deal with saving and showing images.

But I'm having problems to show my picture.

I have two models: Property and Picture.

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, reject_if: :all_blank,      allow_destroy: true
    enum property_type: [:Terreno, :Casa, :Apartamento]
end
    class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

And my index page

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% @properties.each do |property|%>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <b>Tipo: </b><span><%=property.property_type%></span></br>
          <b>Nome: </b><span><%=property.name%></span></br>
          <%= image_tag property.pictures.first.image.url(:thumb) %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it keep showing in my browse: undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass in this line

```
<%= image_tag property.pictures.first.image.url(:thumb) %>
```

but in terminal it works:

[Here is my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmczk.png)

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If `property.pictures.first` is `nil` then `image` will be an invalid method call. Try guarding against that by using `property.pictures.first.image.url(:thumb) unless property.pictures.first.nil?`

Comment: I've just updated my post and linked an image from my terminal to show that is not nil

Comment: It's possible that in a different environment that it is `nil` by having different access rules or a different style file system. Add the `unless` clause and it should work.

Comment: Your terminal code shows one Property, the last one. In your views, you iterate over all the properties. Your code only works if all the properties have at least one picture.

Comment: `Propery.select{|property| property.pictures.empty?}` to find the properties with no picture.

Comment: One of your properties does not have a thumbnail. Easy fix: Your Drop the database, migrate again. You'll probably find that it will work. It's obviously better to pinpoint the fault, but this will likely work.

Comment: Thanks @stephenmurdoch, it worked.